# Chart JS display Data Value on the top of the Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I m begginning with CHART JS and i've got a problem when i want to display the data Value on the top of each bar and the value disappear when my mouse is hover the bar. The next problem is the value are cropped on the top of the Chart

Here's my code :

```
function assignChart(ctx, dataArray) {
    const dataLabel = ["Paris", "Milan", "London", "Florence", "New York", "Not specified"];

    return (new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: dataLabel,
            datasets: [{
                data: dataArray,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            events: [],
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        display: false,
                        beginAtZero:true,
                    }
                }]
            },
            animation: {
                duration : 1,
                onComplete : function() {
                    var chartInstance = this.chart,
                    ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

                    ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                    this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
                        var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                        meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
                            if (dataset.data[index] > 0) {
                                var data = dataset.data[index];
                                ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

Ps : i'm using ChartJS 2.7.3

Comment: I have created this fiddle from your code, I don't see the issue mentioned by you happening there. Can you modify it and let me know. https://jsfiddle.net/x75ehyco/1/

Comment: The problem is when value is set to 10 in the array the value on the top don't appear. You can see this on the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kL6p0594/7/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the problem of yours the data labels getting cropped on the top, you can add padding to the through the layout option like this:

```
layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 15,
        bottom: 0
      }
    }
```

See fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/xys1tqfn/1/